# Derivation of Rational Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$V - \frac{(1+g)V}{1+i} = \frac{D(1+g)}{1+i}$$

Simplify for $V$

The final equation is $$V = \frac{D(1+g)}{i-g}$$. Please explain the steps.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE.  Please check this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on formatting your math equations.

Comment: to be true, you need $g\ne i\ne -1$

Comment: $g$ can equal $-1$, it just can't equal $i$.

Comment: Also, it could help greatly that you add context in order to have better answers!

Comment: This equation is a step in the derivation of the Gordon Growth Model.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why one can simplify on just one side of the equation?

Answer (score 1):

If $i \neq g$,
$$ \frac{D(1+g)}{1+i}= V - \frac{(1+g)V}{1+i} =V \left(1-\frac{(1+g)x}{1+i}\right)=V\left(\frac{1+i-(1+g)}{1+i}\right)=V\left(\frac{i-g}{1+i}\right) \\ \overset{(1)}{\iff} (1+g)D= V(i-g) 
\overset{(2)}{\iff} V = \frac{D(1+g)}{i-g}$$

(1) multiply both sides by $1+i$.

(2) divide both sides by$(i-g)$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying both sides by $1+i$ yields:

$$(1+i)V-(1+g)V=D(1+g)$$
$$(1+i-1-g)V=D(1+g)$$
$$(i-g)V=D(1+g)$$
$$V=\frac{D(1+g)}{i-g}$$

Answer (score 0):

Factor out V from the left side:
$$
V\left(1-\frac{1+g}{1+i}\right) = D \frac{1+g}{1+i}
$$
Simplify 
$$
1-\frac{1+g}{1+i} = \frac{1+i-1-g}{1+i} = \frac{i-g}{1+i}
$$
Divide both sides by $\frac{i-g}{1+i}$
$$
V = \frac{1+i}{i-g} D\frac{1+g}{1+i} = D\frac{1+g}{i-g}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the left hand side first:

$$V - \frac{(1+g)V}{1+i} = \frac{(1+i)V}{1+i} - \frac{(1+g)V}{1+i} = V\left(\frac{i-g}{1+i}\right)$$

Then
$$V\left(\frac{i-g}{1+i}\right) = \frac{D(1+g)}{1+i}$$

Multiply both sides by the common denominator $1 + i$:

$$V(i-g)=D(1+g)$$
$$V = \frac{D(1+g)}{i-g}$$

You need $i - g \neq 0$ otherwise the denominator is $0$ and $V$ is undefined.